# How to get openssl to work on Debian 9.5

Tags: debian, openssl

This is my distribution I use

```
  root@ci-server:~/temp# lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Debian
    Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
    Release:        9.5
    Codename:       stretch
```

When installing openssl I receive the following message but using `openssl` just simply does not work

```
root@ci-server:~/temp# apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0j-1~deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
root@ci-server:~/temp# openssl version
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but `libcrypto.so.1.1` was found here

```
root@ci-server:~/temp# find / -name "libcrypto.so.1.1"
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

`ldconfig` contents

```
root@ci-server:~# cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

and

```
root@ci-server:~# ls -l /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38 Jan 17  2017 fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44 Mar 20  2016 libc.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 Jan 14  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
```

looking for `/usr/lib64` within `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` did not yield any results

```
root@ci-server:~# grep -irl "/usr/lib64" /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
root@ci-server:~#
```

Comment: It might be an `ldconfig` problem. Could you share the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` (and or `.d`)? [A guide for reference](https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-fix-shared-object-file-error/)

Comment: @rudib did as u wish in an edit

Comment: Ok, is the path `/usr/lib64` listed in any of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`?

Comment: @rudib updated question

Comment: That should be the problem. You could create a new file, like `lib64.conf` and place the path in there. And then rebuild the cache with `sudo ldconfig`. Or you could just place a symlink in one of the directories that are listed.

Comment: I saw that the libs are placed in `/usr/local/lib` so I copied them from the lib64 path. Is this a valid approach as well or just a temp fix

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to copy them as that might infere with updates/installs. But a symlink or a modified ld.so.conf should be fine. (As updates for example will be placed in the original folder and thereby wouldn't be applied if you didn't copy the file again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected location for `libcrypto.so.1.1` in Debian 9.5 is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1`, not `/usr/lib64`... and the package that contains it is `libssl1.1`, which contains the libraries of OpenSSL; in Debian packaging, the `openssl` package contains only the configuration files, the `/usr/bin/openssl` and `/usr/bin/c_rehash` command binaries and the associated man pages. The `openssl` package (and anything that requires OpenSSL libraries) depends on `libssl1.1`. This way, the package management allows you to install just the libraries if you don't need the `openssl` command-line tool and are building e.g. an embedded system with minimal amount of storage space available.

On a fresh installation of Debian 9.x on x86_64 architecture, `/usr/lib64` should not even exist. The fact that it exists suggests that another copy of `openssl` may have been installed from some alternative source (perhaps by copying the binaries from another host, or by installing packets intended for other distributions).

Please run `dpkg --verify libssl1.1 openssl` to verify the integrity of `libssl1.1` and `openssl` packages on your system. The output will list any files that have been modified: if e.g. the `/usr/bin/openssl` binary is listed in the output, you'll know that your system's `openssl` has been tampered with.

The worst-possible scenario is that your system has been hacked and the intruder has tried to replace your OpenSSL with a modified version that will leak your private keys to the intruder. If so, then the intruder made a mistake, probably by using a set of libraries intended for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora-style systems (where the `/usr/lib64` path is typically used) on your Debian system.

If you think your system might be hacked: **don't panic**. Server Fault has a [canonical answer on what to do if you suspect your server has been compromised by a hacker.](https://serverfault.com/a/218011/442837)